# Is the sentence "I am already working on this project and it is almost code complete." grammatically correct?

Tags: meaning, word-request

> I am already working on this project and it is almost **code complete**.

Is this a correct use of "code complete"? I know that it is [a book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0735619670) but I am not sure if this is the right way to say it as a non-native speaker. This is sort of a grammatical question but related to programming.

(I'd say this as  "I'm almost finished coding.")

Answer (score 4):

This is an example of ***lingo***

> [**lingo**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lingo) : *b : the special vocabulary of a particular field of interest*

Here "code complete" indicates a stage or milestone in the software development lifecycle.

As is the case with all specialized vocabulary it should be used only with an audience who is expected to be able to understand it.

In this particular case, the usage is quite informal and to maintain the same register I'd suggest using contractions and I'd probably still use scare quotes around it:

> **I'm** already working on it and **it's** almost "code complete".

Otherwise in a more formal setting, something like:

> This work has already been started and coding is nearly complete.

might be better.

Comment: +1 for suggesting *scare quotes*, alerting us to the fact that we're dealing with a "geek jargon" usage here. Although paradoxically, it would be the *lack* of scare quotes that would make me think the writer was a linguistically-challenged geek. When they *are* included, I make no such assumption about the writer himself - it's just a readily-understood shorthand form.

Answer (score 2):

You could say "I am already working on this project and am almost done writing the implementation."

If you must use the word "code", then say "I am already working on this project and am almost done writing the code."

Answer (score 1):

"Feature-complete" would likely be more clear to everyone, including non-technical folk.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question:  "Is this a correct use of *code complete*"

Comment: @Jim: In the context of programmer work, yes it is.

Comment: Hmmm, In the context of the English Language, a "Yes/No" question is typically answer by either yes or no, sometimes followed by an explanation for why.  So are you saying that OP's use of *code complete* is incorrect and that *feature complete* is the proper term?

Comment: In this context, "code complete" is in reference to the the code written to complete a specific feature. As "code complete" is generally meaningless to non-techie folk (and can lend itself to incorrect interpretation to techies), "code complete" is the incorrect term and "feature complete" is correct.

Comment: I'm also not entirely sure why this was migrated from programmers.se as it's more a programmer communication issue than one of the use of the English language.

Comment: I would make a distinction between "code complete" and "feature complete".  "Feature Complete" discusses functionality from a user-perspective- Do all the buttons work? Does it implement the requirements etc.  But it may have been coded for the "sunny-day path" only.  The programmer may still claim they need to "go in and clean up the code" even after it's been deemed "feature-complete".

Comment: As a developer, I would agree with this statement.  _Code complete_ & _feature complete_ are frequently different things.